# $T$ self-adjoint on Hilbert space $H$, $T^n=T^{n+1}$ will $T$ be an orthogonal projection operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have seen several answers and proofs here at MSE that a self-adjoint operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ where $T^2=T$, implies $T$ being an orthogonal projection operator.

The thought struck me; what would happen if the condition $T^2=T$ is replaced by $T^3=T^2$ or instead by $T^4=T^3$ or why not more generally by $T^n=T^{n+1}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Would this still imply $T$ to be an orthogonal projection operator?

I guess someone must have thought of this before me? In that case perhaps there is a reference in the literature for this or perhaps the proof is way simpler than I might expect?

Comment: I think any nilpotent operator will have some $n$ such that $T^n = T^{n+1}=0$. But they aren't orthogonal of course.

Comment: From the identity $||T||^k = ||T^k||$ it is clear that no selfadjoint operator can be nilpotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n = 0$, the condition $T^{n+1} = T^n$ says $T = \operatorname{id}$, so $T$ is an orthogonal projection. For $n \geqslant 1$, the condition yields $T^n = T^{n+1} = T^{(n+1) + 1} = T^{n+2} = \dotsc = T^{2n} = (T^n)^2$, so $T^n$ is an orthogonal projection. But if $T^n$ is the orthogonal projection onto $S$, then $T^n = T^{n+1}$ says $T\lvert_S = \operatorname{id}_S$, and since $T$ is self-adjoint, $S^{\perp}$ is a $T$-invariant subspace too. And $T\lvert_{S^{\perp}}$ is then a self-adjoint nilpotent operator, hence $T\lvert_{S^{\perp}} = 0$. But then $T = T^n$ is the orthogonal projection onto $S$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand some parts of your answer, for example why would $T^n = T^{n+1} = T^{(n+1) + 1}$ be true by using $T^n=T^{n+1}$ and that $T$ is self-adjoint?

Comment: That uses only $T^n = T^{n+1}$, thus $T^{n+2} = T^{n+1}T = T^nT = T^{n+1}$ etc. The self-adjointness is used for the rest; that $T^n$ is an orthogonal projection, and that the orthogonal complement of its range is $T$-invariant, hence the restriction of $T$ self-adjoint, hence zero.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Lastly, why is $T=T\lvert_{S^{\perp}}+T\lvert_{S}$? Did you use linearity of $T$ and why is $T$ linear?

Comment: Does the linearity follow by using $\| T(y+z)-(Ty+Tz) \|^2=0$ where $y\in S$ and $z\in S^\perp$? In that case for $x_1,x_2\in H$ with $\alpha_1, \alpha_2\in \mathbb{C}$ it should be able to show that $\| T(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)-(\alpha_1Tx_1+\alpha_2Tx_2) \|^2=0$ i guess, by just playing around with self-adjointness property?

Comment: Isn't linearity [part of the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator)?

Comment: Oops, I mixed up my thoughts a bit there. Does an idempotent and self-adjoint operator imply orthogonal projection as you show $T^n$ is, even if $T^n$ would be an unbounded operator? I can only find propositions for this to be implied when the operator is self-adjoint, bounded and idempotent.

Answer (score 3):

A selfadjoint operator $T$ has the property that $\mathcal{N}(T)=\mathcal{N}(T^2)$ because $$\|Tx\|^2=\langle T^2x,x\rangle \le \|T^2x\|\|x\|.$$ Therefore, if $T^{n+1}=T^{n}$, then $T^{n}(T-I)=0$ implies $T(T-I)=0$, which is the condition for an orthogonal projection.

Comment: You show $\mathcal{N}(T^2)\subset \mathcal{N}(T)$? How do you get equality?

Comment: Did you make use of $\Vert T^2 x\Vert^2\le \Vert T^3 x\Vert \Vert Tx \Vert$?

Comment: @noidea $\|Tx\|^2 \le \|T^2x\|\|x\|$ implies that, if $T^2x =0$ for some $x\ne 0$, then $Tx=0$. Therefore, if $T^{n}x=0$ for $n \ge 2$, then $T^2T^{n-2}x=0 \implies TT^{n-2}x=0$ or $T^{n-1}x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$T$ is orthogonally diagonalisable, i.e., $T=U^*DU$, where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ orthogonal.

If $T^n=T^{n+1}$, for some $n$, then, $D^{n+1}=D^n$, and hence every diagonal element $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda^n=\lambda^{n+1}$, and thus $\lambda\in\{0,1\}$. So all the eigenvalues of $D$ are ones or zeroes and therefore $T$ is an orthogonal projection.